# How to set OpenCV Android SDK environment variable

Tags: android, c++, opencv, native, android.mk

I want to integrate a C++ library with my Android project using the Android NDK. I've naturally put the library in `src/main/cpp` folder and tried to build the app. However, the following error comes up:

```
SIMPLE: Build command failed.


SIMPLE: Error while executing process /FwzFiles/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/FwzFiles/GitHub/FaceRecognitionApp/app/src/main/cpp/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/FwzFiles/GitHub/FaceRecognitionApp/app/src/main/cpp/Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=/FwzFiles/GitHub/FaceRecognitionApp/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/FwzFiles/GitHub/FaceRecognitionApp/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib NDK_DEBUG=1 NDEBUG=null APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


ERROR: *** Please specify environmental variable OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK to OpenCV Android SDK directory.  Stop.
Open File
```

Even though I've already downloaded the [OpenCV SDK](https://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-android/2.4.13/opencv-2.4.13.6-android-sdk.zip) and set a system (Linux) environment variable pointing to it - in my system it is at `/FwzFiles/OpenCV-android-sdk` - I still get this error.
This is part of my `Android.mk` :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

ifndef OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK
  $(error Please specify environmental variable OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK to OpenCV Android SDK directory)
endif

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES := on
include $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK)/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

ifndef EIGEN3_DIR
  $(error Please specify environmental variable EIGEN3_DIR to Eigen 3 directory)
endif
```

So how do I point `OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK` to a location in my filesystem?